# What information can I ask as the owner of a website to the clients of site?

Tags: copyright, canada, intellectual-property, terms-of-service

I am not knowledgeable when it comes to IP and copyrights ! Any replies are greatly appreciated!

I am planing to go on Kickstarter with a website that offers speech synthesis to its users. I want legal protection for my users and myself. I do not want the software to be used by others in a malicious fashion. My thoughts to limit that would be ask the site users to register with me using information that will deflect them from being bad. I have three questions.

1. What kind of information can I legally ask of my users, proof of employment, job letter, banking info ?
2. Most importantly how can this information be kept safely, I am just a c++ programmer. Are there agencies that will keep this information safe or is it on me to safe guard?
3. The software can make copies of all synthesized speech summited to it. I can see it milliseconds before anyone else. Can I copyright on the fly or make the user sign away the right to copyright to me?

The software is implemented in a S.A.A.S. model (Software As A Service) like photoshop and the rest of CCS. In this model all speech simulations are conducted on a my backend and then submitted to the user. It features a synthesizer interface for the client to play around with and set conditions.

Comment: If I use your service to read my own work like an essay, etc., are you trying to say in your terms of service that you then own the copyright to the speech synthesized production of that essay?

Comment: When you ask for too much information, you won't get that many users. Your service would need to be extremely awesome to persuade me to give you just a single one of the documents mentioned in #1. Not just because I am privacy-conscient, but also because it is very inconvenient for me to provide that information. When you want your service to become widely used you need to make it as easily accessible as possible.

Comment: @Brandin I want own the copy of recording made by my software, I don't want to own the underling piece of work i.e the essay,lyrics,etc. I then want to license that recording back to the user i.e vocals for a song(fee for use), call directory(monthly/yearly fee), narration/voice over(hopefully), video game use. I just want to make small slivers off each use. Every time someone profits from it I want to wet my beak too :)

Comment: @Vincent Well, just as an analogy since you mentioned them, if I use Photoshop to transform my photo, I don't think Adobe have a copyright claim to the transformed photo that I made using their software. I think copyright is for creative works, not output from a computer program.

Comment: @Brandin Yes that was an analogy for the delivery system of the software only. The output of the software is an audio file. Audio can be copyrighted, for instance audio books have copyrights.

Comment: @Vincent If a person produces an audio book using a software program, the creator/author should have the copyright to the audio recording, not the person who wrote the software used in its production.

Comment: Software which takes royalties for products made with it is not unheard of. It's the business model of the [Unreal Engine](https://www.unrealengine.com/what-is-unreal-engine-4), for example, which wants a 5% share when people make money with it. This is usually codified in the EULA.